# JBoss eap 6 JNDI Issue

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I am trying out the following tutorial which creates a simple EJB and then accesses via a Java SE client: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/ejb_create_application.htm

This tutorial uses ant but I am using maven. Now, in my client, I am getting the following error while creating the initial context:

```
 javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:    
 org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at EJBDriver.main(EJBDriver.java:21)
```

I have added the following dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>

     <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
```

Finally, the jndi properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:4447
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems to be that the client jar is not in the classpath, check this point: Add jboss libraries using Add jar/folder button in compile tab. Jboss libraries can be located at <jboss installation folder>> client folder.

Comment: I solved the problem the same way. Add it as a seperate comment and I,ll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows

1- If the EJB classes are in different projects, than the project with EJB  classes needs to be added to the classpath of the project containing the client. For Eclipse:

Right Click on project->Build Path->Configure Build Path-> Projects tab->Add->Select the desired project->OK->OK

2- The jboss-client.jar file needs to be added to the class path of the EJB client project as well.

Right Click on project->Build Path->Configure Build Path-> Projects tab->Librariers->Add External JAR
Browse to the jboss-client.jar file(In windows its located in JBoss_Installation/bin/client)
Select the file and click OK twice.

Answer (score 0):

jboss 6 should use the following properties:

```
naming factory= org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
provider url= remote://localhost:4447
```